# Gatling write to file ONLY when session status is http 500

Tags: gatling

I need to wash some testdata and want to write to a file only when I get HTTP 500 in response. I also get 504 and 502 when running the washing job.

I tried this but it does not write to the file:

```
val writer4: PrintWriter = {
val fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("pasienter_feiler.txt")
new java.io.PrintWriter(fos, true)}
```

---

```
.exec((session: io.gatling.core.session.Session) => {
if (session.status == 500) {
writer4.println(session.attributes("identifier"))
}
session
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First need separated all != 500 `.check(status.not(500))`

And add FileAppender to your logback-test.xml

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
      <file> logs.txt </file>
      <append>true</append>
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

<root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />    
</root>
```